# Sort an arrayList with multiple objects

Tags: java, object, arraylist

I made a list of `Animal`s as follows :

```
        ArrayList<Animal> animals = new ArrayList<Animal>();
        animals.add(new Animal(1, "animal1", 50, "10 Janvier 2016", "Noir", 4, true));
        animals.add(new Animal(2, "animal2", 50, "10 Janvier 2016", "Noir", 4, true));
        animals.add(new Animal(3, "animal3", 50, "10 Janvier 2016", "Noir", 4, true));
        animals.add(new Animal(4, "animal4", 50, "10 Janvier 2016", "Noir", 4, true));
        animals.add(new Animal(5, "animal5", 50, "10 Janvier 2016", "Noir", 4, true));
```

I want to sort my list of animals in `ArrayList` by their ID. From what i've seen i have to use a comparator.

This is what i created so far...

```
public class ComparatorAnimal implements Comparator<Animal> {

    public int compare(Animal animals.get(0), Animal animals.get(1) {
        return animals.get(0).idAnimal - animals.get(1).idAnimal;
    }
```

Comment: The `Comperator` interface actually tells you the signature of the method that you do have to implement. If you don´t have a method with this signature inside your class then it would not compile, which i guess is the case right now. Well and you can´t name your variables like `animals.get(0)`

Comment: This type of questions have been asked and answered multiple times. It's a duplicate question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
public class ComparatorAnimal implements Comparator<Animal> {

public int compare(Animal animals.get(0), Animal animals.get(1) {
    return animals.get(0).idAnimal - animals.get(1).idAnimal;
}
```

The method signature is wrong: you are not comparing two lists of `Animal` but two `Animal` object.
Then you are comparing two id, you don't need to subtract it. Just use the same method from the Integer class.

Change your method like this:

```
public class ComparatorAnimal implements Comparator<Animal> {

public int compare(Animal o1, Animal o2) {
    return Integer.compare(o1.idAnimal, o2.idAnimal);
}
```

Now you have to use a sorted collection (like TreeMap instead of ArrayList) or invoke `Collections.sort(yourList, yourComparator)`

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
public int compare(Animal animals.get(0), Animal animals.get(1) {
    return animals.get(0).idAnimal - animals.get(1).idAnimal;
}
```

to

```
public int compare(Animal animal1, Animal animal2 {
    if(animal1.idAnimal > animal2.idAnimal)
        return 1;
    else if(animal1.idAnimal < animal2.idAnimal)
        return -1;

    return 0;
}
```

& then use

```
Collections.sort(animals, new ComparatorAnimal());
```